# Can I increase the gain of a wifi dongle by attaching an external Yagi Antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am planning to buy a USB Wireless-N TP-Link TL-WN722N 150Mbps Network Adapter which has an 4dBi detachable antenna .Would I able to increase the gain of the wifi dongle by buying an extra YAGI ANTENNA 12 DBI  and connecting it?

http://www.computeralliance.com.au/usb-wireless-n-tp-link-tl-wn722n-150mbps-network-adapter?s=0&gclid=Cj0KEQjwoM63BRDK_bf4_MeV3ZEBEiQAuQWqkbfEiJAkx6DKj9sFSjavj52tZAovGg9DWn0rJN7gb_0aAgNL8P8HAQ

http://www.dreamkart.com.au/900-1800mhz-gsm-yagi-antenna-12-dbi-n-male-connector-cable-length-15m.html?gclid=CjwKEAjww9O3BRDp1tq0jIP023YSJAB0-j1SaCXu8hxqmf3Y66Y6fU2sxSDM0hNdirOyRb94JB5m4xoC5tLw_wcB

Comment: Sure, why not. Perhaps the dongle has no such connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yagi has 12 dBi gain, but it's directional, only covers the band from 900 to 1800MHz and has a female "N" connector, so the short answer is "NO."

TP-LINK, on the other hand offers some [**8dBi omni whips**](http://www.tp-link.us/products/list-4765.html) which work up at 2600MHz and  come with a male RP-SMA connector, so it'll plug right into the network adapter.

Plus, it'll be street legal and you won't have to worry about compliance.

Comment: ok What if I found an external Yagi Antenna that has a male RP-SMA connector? Can connect it to the TP-LINK?

Comment: How can I connect a external Yagi to the TP-link ?

Comment: I Just need a very high gain antenna such as an directional antenna attached on the TP-LINK modem

Comment: @JoneJamson  
`How can I connect a external Yagi to the TP-link ?`  That sounds like a separate question to me...

Comment: Sorry , my purpose is to connect any type  of Yagi to the TP-link to achieve a greater gain then 9dBi like 14dBi or above . Would this be possible if I found one that has a male RP-SMA connector?

Comment: @JoneJamson:  TL link has antennas, cables, and even a cable that'll allow you to go from N Male to RP-SMA [here](http://www.tp-link.us/products/list-5063.html) so you can hook up your Yagi if you want to. But why would you want to if it's operating out of band

Comment: @JoneJamson:  TL link has antennas, cables, and even a cable that'll allow you to go from N Male to RP-SMA [**here**](http://www.tp-link.us/products/list-5063.html) so you can hook up your Yagi if you want to. But why would you want to if it's operating out of band and won't give you the gain and directivity you want? . Google "wifi Yagi" for sources to everything you need to get your job done.